# How to calculate 256d array vector of face embeddings just like 128d in python opencv.?

Tags: python, face

I am using below code to get the `128d array vector` of face embeddings.

```
embedder = cv2.dnn.readNetFromTorch('openface_nn4.small2.v1.t7')

embedder.setInput(face_blob)  # face_blob is the blob of face image
vec = embedder.forward()      # vec contains the 128d
```

How can I calculate the `256d array vector` like above for a face image.? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to build your own or modify the existing NN, so it returns 256d instead of 128d from the last layer. Could be as simple as replacing `Dense( 128, ...)` to `Dense( 256, ...)' or as complicated as retraining the whole network after that replacement.

Comment: @SAndrew probably you may start from the source code for your network (openface_nn4.small) and see what are the latest layers, it could be like `Dense(512)` then `Dense(256)` and then `Dense(128)` -- in this case you just remove the last layer and that's all. Otherwise you might need to build the different network, collect some data, train it, etc... BTW, why do you think 128d embedding is not enough for your purpose ?

Comment: I am dealing with the faces which is low detailed, or smoothed, or jpeg-compressed-high-loss, the recognition is very error-prone. So I thought instead of 128d, I should try with 256d. Do you think 256d will help much better.?

Comment: @SAndrew from my experience 128d vector is plenty enough to describe every face on the planet many millions times over, so 256d would be generally an overkill. I'd rather spend time on data collection (getting better images) and preparation (face detection, alignment, etc.) -- this would definitely let you get the better results.

Comment: I think face alignment is a good point you have raised which I have not consider yet. I will also include this before extracting the 128d face emebeddings. Thanks